# C# WebUtility.HtmlDecode returns "?"

Tags: c#, console-application

```
String Text = "This is example &#148;Text&#148;";
Text = WebUtility.HtmlDecode(Text);
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"c:\x.txt", Text, Encoding.ASCII);
```

Correct output:

```
This is example ”Text”
```

Output of x.txt:

```
This is example ?Text?
```

Comment: You're trying to use ASCII, which doesn't include Unicode character 148. Your "correct output" couldn't possibly be written while using ASCII.

Comment: How do I get the correct output?

Comment: @user2886646 try `"This is example &#8216;Text&#8217;"`

Comment: @L.B I want to save HTML text from website to text file with decoded characters. Changing original text doesn't work for me.

Comment: @user2886646: Well you need to have some definition of "correct output" which is actually viable to start with. Using UTF-8 would be a good start, if you're able to.

Comment: @JonSkeet All I want to achieve is to be able to decode text from website, so it wouldn't have encoded characters. Changing Encoding to Encoding.UTF8 didn't do the trick.

Comment: It looks like that HTML is using Code Page 1252 to start with - character 148 in CP1252 is the character you expect, but 148 in Unicode isn't.

Comment: @user2886646: I believe the problem is that HtmlDecode assumes that the encoded HTML is using Unicode values for the encoded values. I can't find anything at the moment which allows you to specify that encoding...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the "iso-8859-1" encoding:

Change

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"c:\x.txt", Text, Encoding.ASCII);
```

with

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"c:\x.txt", Text, Encoding.GetEncoding(28591));
```

Comment: The problem occurs before this, I believe.

Comment: @user2886646: That's actually due to coincidence, I believe - whatever you're using to read the file is *treating* it as CP1252, even though you've *written* it as ISO-8859-1. Your `Text` string contains U+0094, which is *not* curly quotes.

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes, I figured that. But why this site http://www.url-encode-decode.com/urldecode provides the correct answer?

Comment: @AhmedKRAIEM: Because the authors of the site don't understand what "ASCII" means? It's a common problem. (The fact that it refers to "8-bit ASCII" is a pretty strong indication of that...)

Comment: @JonSkeet references to characters 128–159 are commonly interpreted by lenient web browsers as if they were references to the characters assigned to bytes 128–159 (decimal) in the Windows-1252 character encoding. So U+0094 _is_ interpreted as `”`.

Comment: @AhmedKRAIEM: Sure, but that doesn't mean that you have to produce a file in this way. If you could specify the encoding to use for numerically-encoded characters, you could then write it in a more sensible encoding, such as UTF-8. Try to reduce the brokenness in the world rather than propagating it.